# HTML Agility Pack Select all node that contain XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm new to the HTML agility pack and I understand the basics of XPath.

However I'm having an issue, is there any way to get all the nodes that contain another type of node?

For example: I want to get all of the `<tr>` that contain an `<a>` tag?

Whenever I do `//tr/a` what I end up with are the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[condition]` is XPath way of saying "where". So your XPath would be something like `//tr[a]` or if you need deeper child nodes use appropriate [axis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `//tr[descendant::a]`.

There are some useful samples on MSDN - [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)